# Angular2: How do you pass a selected item from a HTML datalist element back to the component?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html-datalist

I have simple component which includes a  to dreate a drop-down box. This is list is filled with the results from a Web API call. For display purposes I only use two fields of the item. However, once an element has been selected I need to do stuff with all the other fields. How do I pass the entire element back to the component?

Really would appreciate any help.

```
<h1>Get Locations</h1>
<div>
    <div>
        <input list="browsers" name="browser" #term (keyup)="search(term.value)">
        <datalist id="browsers">
            <option *ngFor="let item of items | async" >
                {{item.code + " " + item.description}}
            </option>
        </datalist>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Click" (click)="onSelect(item)" />
</div>
```

The component code is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit }        from '@angular/core';
import { Observable }       from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject }          from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { LocationService } from './location.service';
import {Location} from './location.component';
import './rxjs-operators';

@Component({
    selector: 'lesson-08',
    templateUrl: './views/lesson08.html',
    providers: [LocationService]
})
export class Lesson08 implements OnInit{

    constructor(private locationService: LocationService) { }

    aLoc: Location;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.aLoc = new Location();
    }

    errorMessage: string;
    locations: Location[];
    mode = 'Observable';
    displayValue: string;

    private searchTermStream = new Subject<string>();

    search(term: string) {
        this.searchTermStream.next(term);
    }

    onSelect(item: Location) {
        // do stuff with this location

    }

    items: Observable<Location[]> = this.searchTermStream
        .debounceTime(300)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap((term: string) => this.locationService.search(term));
    }
```

Comment: What if the user doesn't select an item from the datalist but rather types their own input? I think you basically have two choices, map the datalist results in a map in your component, and look up the original object based on user input, or do a 2nd search once user input has completed

Comment: Entering their own input would not be allowed in this case. Well, that is the intention. Additional lookup is exactly what I am trying to avoid. The Web API already returns a type of Location, which has all the data attributes I need. Could you clarify what you mean by "map the datalist results in a map" ? Thanks

Comment: When query data returns as an array map it into an object keyed by the display string. Example `var m={}; arrayData.forEach (d=>m[keyOf (d)]=d);`

Comment: I am facing same.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (click) event calling the method should be on the option selected. Your declared "item" is only known in the scope of the *ngFor, so on the levels of its children. You declared it on a too high level.